# Forcing talkback to read some specific characters - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, accessibility, talkback

I would like to make the talkback say a simple mathematical expression like: "2 - (3/5)"

However, when it reads, talkback skips the parentheses, thus affecting the expression to take on a different meaning.

Thanks to @QuentinC I was able to read more questions on the subject. Would this fall under "it's best to leave it at that and not edit" cases, or should I instead be looking for ways to force talkback to speak every character?

Comment: Have you checked talkback’s settings? How screen readers read is highly customizable. And providing some more context might help: Why is there only an opening parentheses, what’s the rest?

Comment: Please have a look at these questions, they are very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175274/how-can-we-direct-a-screenreader-to-emphasize-stress-pronounce-words-correctly/75179175
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72250258/get-screen-readers-to-pronounce-well-known-acronyms/72261923
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73988346/replace-sentence-to-read-dash-with-screen-reader-for-accessibility
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74021046/getting-voiceover-to-read-distance-and-time-correctly/74022990

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I thought I simplified the question, but instead I needed to provide some context. I've now updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter we have `Semantics` widget to help with assistive technologies such as TalkBack on Android (or VoiceOver in iOS).

Use `hint` property to set whatever you want assistive technologies to read. Use `excludeSemantics` to make sure the original child widget (`Text` widget, in this case) is suppressed, so that you won't hear the same content twice.

For example:

```
Semantics(
  excludeSemantics: true,
  hint: '2 minus bracket 3 over 5', // <-- whatever you want it to read
  child: const Text('2 - (3/5)'),
)
```